# Charging for a ipad app that uses other peoples apis

Tags: ipad

Looking for some advise

I have been developing a ipad app that i am looking to release shortly but i am asking for advise on cost.

Basically my ipad app uses googles image api and it also uses you tubes and twitters api, so its kind of a mashup of various technologies.

Can i charge for my app i was only thinking 69pence but i am not sure if this is allowed and have no experience in releasing apps, i would like to try and make some profit if possible and have looked at the various advertising options iads etc.

What are apple policies on charging for a ipad app using various apis??? can someone update me or even just point me in the right direction for a forum to ask on i have tried here https://devforums.apple.com/index.jspa but its mainly developer based and not general discussion.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to read the fine print on each of the APIs that you are using. Social APIs will likely (but not guaranteed) be free to use without charge - their business model is to have people using their network so they want developers to enable this for them. Good luck with your first App!

Comment: thanks micheal for the feedback all a bit over my head at the moment the dos and don'ts, if i did charge for it and they decide the are not happy with it i suppose i leave myself open to be sued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in Apple iOS Developer Agreement to prevent you from charging for such an app.

You should ensure that you are entitled to use the API you mention for a commercial purpose (which I understand should be normally the case, but you will know better).

You should also ensure that the way you use the content you get through that API is legally sound. The problem here arises from the fact that content from YouTube and google images is protected by copyright in its own. Maybe it is the case you can claim for fair-use, maybe it is not... it depends on what you do with the content.

As to the consequences of a breach of the API or copyright, I think that if your app becomes hugely successful, then chances are you could get a request for money; if your app will just sell as most apps do, then no one will notice. Just my guess, no guarantees implied!! :-)

Comment: thanks sergio great advise, im not doing anything with the content that i think they will disapprove of just allowing people to search a related topic with those apis.